# Why can't I see my jQuery UI animation?

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui, z-index

I have an element that's going into a slideshow, and when the slide comes in, this element uses the jQuery UI effect `explode` to appear.

```
$e.show('explode', {}, 1000);
```

When I first ran it, I didn't see the element appear at all. So I thought "Oh, it must be z-index" and set the element's z-index to 10 and made sure it had `position` defined. (The slide's z-index is 5)

This made the image show up *after* the effect is complete. I hid the slide to test, and sure enough, the animation was happening behind the slide, seemingly with a lower `z-index`.

Why can't I see the element until after the animation?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### What's Happening

When certain elements are animating with jQuery UI, depending on the effect, the element itself may be cloned. The element that you are manipulating ($e) is actually hidden, and not part of the DOM at the time of animation, so your CSS rules are useless here. *Some* of the rules are applied to the cloned element with jQuery, however, z-index is not one of them.

### Fix it With CSS Animations

I suggest using [CSS Animations](http://www.w3schools.com/css3/css3_animations.asp) which directly manipulate your element, and have no need to clone the element. Though this makes effects like `explode` slightly more complex, not only are you maintaining your CSS rules, but CSS animations make for a huge performance gain over jQuery UI animations. (jQuery UI applies each 'step' of the animation individually, meaning many [repaints](http://www.phpied.com/rendering-repaint-reflowrelayout-restyle/)). A limitation with this, however, is cross-browser compatibility, as it looks like IE is still [not up to par with this](http://caniuse.com/css-animation).

### Fix it With z-index

If you're hell-bent on using jQuery UI for your animations, or can't risk the lack of cross-browser compatibility, there is still hope. In my tests, the 'cloned' element gets a class added to it temporarily of `ui-effects-explode`. It seems that most jQuery UI animations that require cloning the original element apply a class with similar syntax (`ui-effects-*`).

Your catch-all to save yourself the frustration on individual effects is to make a CSS-rule like the following:

```
[class^=ui-effects] {
    z-index: 10;
}
```

Where `^=` means 'begins with'. This will apply the z-index to any cloned elements within jQuery UI namespace, and should resolve your issue.